# BigQuery conditional date formatting based on the value

Tags: date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need some help around BigQuery date formatting based on their values. The source data has STRING datatype and target datatype is DATE. I need to format the input dates based on their values as follow:

[image]

1. NULL value should remain NULL
2. Empty string("") should be convert to NULL
3. Date with YYYY-MM-DD format should remain as is
4. Date with MM/DD/YYYY format should be convert to YYYY-MM-DD format

Here's what I have done so far:

```
SELECT input_date, CASE WHEN input_date = '' THEN NULL ELSE PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', input_date) END AS output_date FROM mytable
```

The above case statement fails when try to parse the dates with YYYY-MM-DD format. Here's the error I am getting:

[image]

How do I solve for the YYYY-MM-DD date format? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try and consider below approach wherein you will need to add another `WHEN` and then use regex to match the `YYYY-MM-DD` string  and then parse it to your desired date format as shown below.

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select NULL as input_date,
  union all select '' as input_date,
  union all select '2022-05-21' as input_date,
  union all select '05/25/2022' as input_date
)
SELECT input_date, 
  CASE WHEN input_date = '' THEN NULL
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(input_date, r'^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$') THEN PARSE_DATE('%F', input_date)
  ELSE PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', input_date) END AS output_date FROM sample_data
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Scott B for the response. It's helpful and along the line with mine where I solved it using IF statement inside the ELSE clause as follow:  `WITH data AS (
  SELECT NULL AS input_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '' AS input_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-05-21' AS input_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '05/25/2022' AS input_date
)
SELECT
  input_date,
  CASE WHEN input_date = '' THEN NULL
  ELSE IF((REGEXP_CONTAINS(input_date, r'^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$') ), DATE(input_date), PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', input_date)) END AS output_date
FROM
  data`

Answer (score 0):

Consider below query:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['', null, '2022-05-21', '05/25/2022']) input_date
)
SELECT *, 
       COALESCE(SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', input_date), SAFE.PARSE_DATE('%F', input_date)) output_date
  FROM sample_data;
```

###### Output results

[image]